# React Native Navigation drawer not opening

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I am newbie in react-native. By searching a lot i found that giving a fixed width to drawer solves the problem. But its not solving in my case. I don't know what is wrong with the code. Every time I run the code, I get the "undefined is not an object". Here is the code.

**This is my Dashboard file**

```
export class Dashboard extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) => ({
    drawerLabel: "Dashboard",
    title: "Dashboard",
    headerLeft: (
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  });
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Dashboard</Text>
    )
  }
}
const MainScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
  DashboardScreen: { screen: Profile },
  ProfileScreen: { screen: Profile },
},
  {
    initialRouteName: "DashboardScreen",
  }
);
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: MainScreenNavigator }
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: 200
  }
);
export default Drawer;
```

**This is my profile file**

```
export class Profile extends Component<NavigationScreenProps<ProfileProps>> {

    constructor(props: NavigationScreenProps<ProfileProps>) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        status: "initial" // initial | failed | success
      }

    }
    static navigationOptions = ( {navigation} : {navigation : any}  ) => ({
      drawerLabel: "Pied Piper",
      title: "Pied Piper",
      headerLeft: (
        <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
            <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="blue" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    });

  render() {
    return (
  <View style={ProfileStyle.container}>
 <Text>Profile</Text>
  </View>
    );
  }

}
export default Profile;
```

Comment: need more specific code

Comment: I have only these file where i am using navigation drawer

Comment: I ran your code with proper import statement from react, react-native & react-navigation (version 1.5.11) and it ran okay without any errors except the drawer item only show one item, in your actual code, do you have proper import statements?

Comment: What are you using JS or TS? In my case i am using TS, maybe in JS this code working fine.